# Filter table based on a cell and move table to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working this way: basically it filters the table based in column A = "Status Changed" and moves the data to different sheet. But I would like to adapt it to do a filter based on a value in a specific cell sheet named "All" cell A1 and not on this value "Status Changed". The criteria1 needs to be a specific cell.
How could I adapt it?

```
Sub Filter_and_move_data()
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Parsing").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
With Worksheets("Incidents_data")
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=Status Changed", Operator:=xlOr
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:G" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets("Parsing").Range("A1")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have an AutoFilter macro example here,[Autofilter MAcro Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogt3PzeRQgg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the expression

```
Criteria1:="=Status Changed"
```

to

```
Criteria1:=Worksheets("All").Range("A1").Value
```